# Definite article "the markets" or "markets"

Tags: grammar

I read on an article about free things to do when travelling

Here is the link:

https://thetravelhack.com/travel-tips/10-free-things-to-do-in-every-city/

**Quote from the article:

> Here are a few of my favorite free things to do in almost every city around the world:
>
> 1. Go on a free walking tour.
> 2. Take an audio tour.
> 3. Explore **the markets**.
> 4. Visiting Free Museums and Galleries.
> 5. Hang out with **the locals.**
> 6. Carnivals, Festivals and Free Performances.

The writer uses "the markets" and "the locals" in the sentences 3 and 5. As I see, no markets or locals mentioned before. And these are not specific markets or locals.
Why is "the" used there?

In the sentences 4,6, the writer don't use "the" such as "**the** Free Museums and Galleries", or "**the** Carnivals, Festivals and Free Performances". I don't know why.

Comment: It's shorthand for 'the markets that are held in the city' (taking it for granted that every city will have more than one) and 'the people who live locally'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may already know this, but for clarity it's worth mentioning that the rule about when to use "the" is that the noun must be *specified* in the context. There is no rule that says the noun must be mentioned before. Mentioning a noun is *one way for something to be specified*, not the only way.

Another way to specify something is for it to be *inherent* in the context. Every city has markets and locals, so it is inherent in talking about a city that there are markets and locals. So "the markets" and "the locals" means "the city's markets" and "the city's locals", asserting that they exist.

However, not every city has free museums, free galleries, carnivals, festivals or free performances. So for those, it makes less sense to use "the".

So, "*Carnivals, Festivals and Free Performances*" implies "***...if any***".

Answer (score 4):

You use "the" if the noun is definite, that is if the speaker and listener will know *which* markets are being referred to.

One way to make a noun definite is to mention it previously, then "the" means that the noun refers to the one that was previously mentioned.

But there are other ways for a noun to be definite.  Common knowledge means that in this case the speaker and listener know from context that "there are some markets in the city" and so the speaker can refer to "the markets".  It means the markets that are in the city.

The same goes for "the locals"="the people who live in the city".  It is common knowledge that there are some people in the city, and the speaker can refer definitely to those people.

On the other hand, it isn't common knowledge that every city has free museums.  So the writer chooses not use "the".  This has the sense of "Free museums (if any exist)"

Similarly, there may not be a festival on the day that you visit.  So it would seem odd to say "the festivals".

Comment: You said "there are some markets in the city"==>" in the city" here mean cites in general. Right? "there are some markets in the city"=" There are some markets in each/every city" . Right?

Comment: In the city that the person is visiting.  Yes again, context implies that there is a definite city, and we can answer the question "which city".